# customization of 3d object in html5

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Is it possible to customize a 3D object (ex mobile phone) as present in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAZR-IPxbag.Here as we are adding a 3D object and then customizing it giving real 3D product view.If it is possible then how can this be achieved?Please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In The video that you have linked they use a 2d image of the phone. They might have took a picture of a 3d phone, or simulated it in 3d, but you you are seeing is a 2d result, which only seems 3d.

If you are looking for actual 3d in the browser (which you probably don't need if you are trying to make something like the one in the video) look for "HTML5 3d libraries" on google.
I would reccomend the http://threejs.org/ library as it is the easiest to use.